# Average values of the top values for different categories

Tags: mysql, sql, average, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 fields, touristic places, the country they're in and the average rating by tourists for this place. I would like to compare different countries based on the average rating of their top touristic places. I use MySQL

It looks like this basically :

```
Eiffel Tower     | France  | 4,2
Trakoscan Castle | Croatia | 4,6
```

For example, how does the average of the notes of the 5 best touristic places in France compare with the average of the notes of the 5 best touristic places in Croatia. I know how to average all places for a country and compare that but I don't know how to combine LIMIT and GROUP BY

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `,` your notation for a decimal point?

Comment: Yes, in France it's a comma instead of a decimal point and I forgot to change it when writing this question ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to filter on the top 5 notes per country, then aggregate.

Assuming that your table has columns `country`, `place` and `rating`, you would phrase the query as:

```
select country, avg(rating) avg_rating_top5
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by country order by rating desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 5
group by country
```

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to update MySQL to a more recent version to ba able to use window functions but then it worked.